# Python3 asyncio There is no current event loop in thread when spawn a new thread

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, coroutine

I can easily reproduce this issue with this example:

```
from threading import Thread
import asyncio

def func():
    asyncio.get_event_loop()

Thread(target=func).start()
```

According to document:

If there is no current event loop set in the current OS thread, the OS thread is main, and set_event_loop() has not yet been called, asyncio will create a new event loop and set it as the current one.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Automatic assignment of a new event loop only happens on the main thread. From the source of asyncio DefaultEventLoopPolicy in `events.py`

```py
def get_event_loop(self):
    """Get the event loop for the current context.

    Returns an instance of EventLoop or raises an exception.
    """
    if (self._local._loop is None and
            not self._local._set_called and
            isinstance(threading.current_thread(), threading._MainThread)):
        self.set_event_loop(self.new_event_loop())

    if self._local._loop is None:
        raise RuntimeError('There is no current event loop in thread %r.'
                            % threading.current_thread().name)

    return self._local._loop
```

So for a non-main thread, you have to manually set the event loop with `asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())`

Comment: I faced this issue while launching Ray Workflows from a (non-main) Python thread. Any help is appreciated, see the issue here: https://discuss.ray.io/t/running-workflows-from-python-thread-runtimeerror-there-is-no-current-event-loop-in-thread/4861